# Enabling/disabling legend and its corresponding row onclick in Google charts

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

My requirement is,

1. After a google chart gets loaded, if I click the legend, the legend should be grayed out and its corresponding value in the graph should be removed.
2. When I click the grayed out legend, the legend should be highlighted as it was before and the removed value should once again be added to the graph.

I am able to do the 50 % of the first part with the below code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      var duplicateChartData = new Array();
       var unSelectedArray = new Array();
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        duplicateChartData = new Array();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        duplicateChartData = data;

         function selectHandler() {
          var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
          var selectedRow = selectedItem.row;
            var isUnSelected = unSelectedArray[selectedRow]
          if (selectedItem && !isUnSelected) {

          data.setValue(selectedRow, 1, 0);
          chart.draw(data, options);
          unSelectedArray[selectedRow] = true;
          }
          if(isUnSelected){
          data.setValue(selectedRow, 1, duplicateChartData.getValue(selectedRow,1));
           unSelectedArray[selectedRow] = false;
          }
        }

        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);    
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I basically setValue as 0 for the selected value and try to reset when clicked again. But whenever a zero is set the legend and data gets deleted. But what I want is thw legend to just gray out. ow to achieve this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I did this for line chart. It satisfies your both requirements. Hope this will help you.

```
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
        var sel = chart.getSelection();
        // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
        if (sel.length > 0) {
            // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
            if (typeof sel[0].row === 'undefined') {
                var col = sel[0].column;
                if (columns[col] == col) {
                    // hide the data series
                    columns[col] = {
                        label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
                        type: data.getColumnType(col),
                        calc: function () {
                            return null;
                        }
                    };

                    // grey out the legend entry
                    series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
                }
                else {
                    // show the data series
                    columns[col] = col;
                    series[col - 1].color = null;
                }
                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                view.setColumns(columns);
                chart.draw(view, options);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the working sample [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-hideshow-lines-in-line-chart/)

Answer (score 1):

Awesome piece of code Abinaya (sorry i cld not +1 im still a newbie here at SO), just what i was looking for, thanks, just a minor correction, based on the comment at jqfaq.com. tried it out and it works 100%.

```
        // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
        //if (typeof sel[0].row === 'undefined') { *** doesn't seem to work
        if (sel[0].row === null) {           // this works
```

checkout the amended [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rM8BM/30/)

I also had been searching for code on how to get the selected legend label and your code also does that using this line of code

```
//get selected legend label
data.getColumnLabel(col)
```

thanks again